# Long response time on socket polling with Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, socket.io

My client is connecting to socket server using `socket.io` 1.0+ lib as:

```
$scope.socket = io.connect( "/gateway" );
```

On server side I launch express server and socket server attached as:

```
httpServer = http.createServer( app ).listen( process.env.PORT, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0", function() { 
    io = require( 'socket.io' )( httpServer ).of("/gateway");
    io.on('connection', function( socket ) {
        // socket events here
    }
});
```

Then the project is tested on heroku. What bother me a lot is [this screen from chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV4we.png)

You can see there that constantly 2 polling requests are being performed. One gets response in couple of **milli**seconds, other one takes somewhere around 26 seconds. If I click on one of them I could see that the real difference between them is request method: the one that uses POST gets quick response, the one uses GET remains in pending state until gets response (or timeout) after ~26 seconds.

In my development enviromnent (c9.io) I do not see this behaviour, but in testing (heroku free node) I get this.

Probably because of this I get some other weird behaviour only on heroku, for example on tab close I do not receive a `disconnect` event, while on c9 I do..

Has anybody faced the same problem? Is there a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the long response was mistreated to a visible open connection when `polling` transport is being used. In this case a 25 second connection is being held open for client-server communication. It is normal, although you have to know about it - some logging modules/solutions may treat it as long response and constantly warn you.

In short

- if the `sebsocket` transport is used there will be one websocket connection open all the time
- is the `polling` transport is used, then every 25-26 seconds a new `GET` connection will be (re)established.